# ¿Como pasar un valor int a ser string, sin usar str()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ejemplo:

```
 NUM=3
```

Covertir esta constante a string pero sin usar la función `str()`.

En python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cualquiera de esta funciona:

```
num_str = "{NUM}".format(NUM=NUM)

num_str = "{}".format(NUM)

num_str = f'{NUM}'

num_str = "% s" % NUM
```

Comment: Esto funciona si es que quieres mostrar el resultado por pantalla ```print()``` pero si se quiere trabajar con la cadena?

Comment: Todas funcionan para convertir el número en cadena. Con cualquiera de esas, ahora tienes el número en formato texto en `num_str`

Comment: @christian Aunque hayas visto generalmente estas funciones utilizadas como argumento de `print()`, realmente son funciones de generación de cadenas. La cadena generada se la puedes pasar a `print()` para que la imprima, o bien guardarla en una variable para procesarla luego, o pasarla como argumento a cualquier otra función que espere un string (como `.write()` para ficheros). No están relacionadas de ningún modo con `print()` salvo porque suelen verse juntas.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias por la aclaración, no sabía sobre eso

Comment: Bueno al final lo que me pedian era que usara las funciones chr() y ord().